# Как запустить задачу в джанго

Tags: python, django

Необходимо по нажатию кнопки запустить формирование документа. Он формируется в функции. Каким образом пользователь может запустить эту функцию и перейти на другую страницу или выйти с сайта, но функция при этом будет работать и завершит свою работу только когда сформирует документ. Пробовал через поток, но он закрывается после потери соединения с пользователем

Comment: почитайте про `celery`

Comment: а потом про `dramatiq`)